# Encode ALL urls in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, encoding, drupal-6

Is there any way to encode ALL urls in Drupal? I.e. Instead of something like this:
 - www.mysite.com/node/add/blog

Will turn the URL into:
 - www.mysite.com/9595kfjfj4fmvmvk4m4mfmkfk44kfk

?

Comment: Just out of curiosity - why would you want to do that? (having clean, readable URLs is usually considered one of Drupals advantages)

Comment: Can't remember why I asked this, but it had something to do with the fact that I didn't want people to know that it's Drupal installed. I.e. Paths like /node and ?q=... etc, should not work. If that makes any sense. I realise now that most of the stuff can just be done with PATH. :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an url alias for any url (with path). You could create a new token for the pathauto module and use it to create your urls, if you want all your urls to look like that. Start looking at those modules, path (core), [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) and [token](http://drupal.org/project/token).

Comment: Note that even with path aliases in place, the original paths still work if accessed directly - you can prevent this with the help of http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect